# How to call an API from dialog flow chatbot

Tags: spring-boot, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

1. How to create webhook.
2. How to create entities in springboot
   3 . How to call an API using dialogue flow

Comment: You can get answer of your questions by googling it, please provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.satishmpandey.tech/creating-a-webhook-for-dialogflow-agent-using-python/. This is in Python but you will get an idea on how to do it.